# "I don't know nothing" vs "I don't know anything"

Tags: differences, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a rule about double negations that aren't meant as double negations (e.g. “We don't need no education”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8777/is-there-a-rule-about-double-negations-that-arent-meant-as-double-negations-e)
>   [Double negation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/double-negation)

I'm not a native English speaker, and this question may be very basic, but I want to learn English better, so don't hurt me with downvotes.

What is the difference between "I don't know nothing" and "I don't know anything"?

Do they have the same meaning or opposite ones?

Comment: NB: “I don’t know nothin’ about that” ≠ “I don’t ***not*** know anything about that”.  The second is a true double negative; the first is still a single negative reinforced through reduplication, which is why it still has a negative sense.  The true double negative alone has positive sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You would consider pretty "uneducated"? According to [this](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pretty?q=pretty) oxford dictionary, it is informal but accepted. I don't have my OED here, unfortunately, but I'm pretty sure I'll find it there too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Technically speaking, it actually isn’t.  Please see my answer below.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Please also make sure to use capital letters and punctuation marks, especially if your stated goal is to learn English better. You might also be interested in supporting our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: @terdon Fumble was talking about the use of the double negative and not "pretty".

Comment: @terdon: I don't know where my original comment has gone (I didn't delete it), but I'm pretty sure I used the word "pretty" to mean "very" myself. And I'm absolutely sure most people would consider me "educated" (including myself! :). Undeniably though, *some* people will think that anyone who's unaware that the usage is relatively "informal", and who therefore uses it "inappropriately" in a more formal context, is uneducated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough, I was most certainly _not_ implying anything as to your level of education :). I agree it is informal, I had just understood your "uneducated" to mean that using pretty in that context is a mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between these two:

- I know nothing about that.
- I don’t know nothin’ about that.

The difference is one of register alone, where the first is standard English and the second is perfectly common but far more casual, and is not generally considered acceptable in formal writing save as reported speech.

**Please note** that the second one is ***not*** a double negative, for if it were, it would be a positive!   And it’s not. Consider this contrasting pair to see the difference:

- I don’t know nothin’ about that. (reinforced negative)
- I don’t ***not*** know anything about that.  (negated negative)

The two components of this second pair are no longer equivalent. The second is-at last a true double-negative. The first is merely a single negative reinforced through ***reduplication***, which is why it still has negative sense.  The true double-negative alone has positive sense.

In English, a double-negative makes a positive, just as a double-positive makes  a negative.

- In the **not utterly unlikely** circumstance that you really do come up with such a thing as a double-positive, surely it must mean the same as a single-positive!
- **“Yeah, sure.”**

Comment: So does "I don't know nothing". If you do not know nothing, you must know something. It is similar to the wonderful "I dind't do nothing" which, strictly speaking, means "I did something".

Comment: @terdon: in Standard English, you would say "I don't know anything" rather than "I don't know nothing", but the *any-* plays *the exact same role* as the *no-* in non-Standard English. That position *requires* a negative-polarity item, it just so happens that Standard English opted for *any*. It could just as well have opted for *no*, and then you'd be wrongfully ridiculing the people who use *any*. Both constructions are completely equivalent. The difference is one of register, not logic.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Perhaps, but English has 'opted' for 'any', therefore, if asked which is correct I will go for the one that is used. Had it 'opted' for _no_ I would have answered differently. In any case, 'any' and 'no' are not equivalent. Compare 'anywhere' to 'nowhere'. By the way, I wasn't ridiculing nobody! :)

Comment: I don't know exactly what *a double-positive makes a negative* means, but I don't think I agree with it. Nor do you, judging by the next sentence.

Comment: AAVE (which is the non-standard English in question) repeats a negative to emphasize negation, which is called **[Negative Concord](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)**. This is normal also in French (_Je ne regrette rien_) and Spanish (_No tiene nada_), and indeed is common worldwide. Standard American English, however, uses a different system called **[Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)**, in which words and phrases like _any, ever, in weeks,_ and _budge_ can only appear inside the scope of some negative.

Comment: @JohnLawler: why do you assume that because one form of English has this peculiarity, no others can have?  I know several people who say 'I don't know nothing', but none of them speak AAVE or have even heard of it.

Comment: @TimLymington *Yeah* is an affirmative response.  *Sure* is an affirmative response.  *Yeah sure* is a negative response.

Comment: @TimLymington: I don't assume that, but it's as good as any dialect for an example. They all use negative concord "no" instead of negative polarity "any". It's the norm; that's the point.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/double-negatives and http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/02/grammar-myths-3/ consider "I don't know nothing" to potentially mean "I know something".

Comment: @tchrist; Riight.