# What is wrong (if anything) with the phrase "it don't mean nothing"?

Tags: grammaticality, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don’t impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)
>   [“I don’t know nothing” vs “I don’t know anything”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78759/i-dont-know-nothing-vs-i-dont-know-anything)

I've noticed that sometimes people say "It don't mean nothing". But I would expect to hear "It doesn't mean anything" or at least "It doesn't mean nothing".

Could anyone clarify why is that? Or it's totally OK to say that?

Here is an example from the movie "Hamburger Hill", http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ernKt7JpNfM

Comment: Not exactly.. I'm mostly interested in "don't" vs. "doesn't" part.

Comment: It's a dialectical variant, African-American or rural Southern, in which the double negative is used in ordinary as an intensifier or even just mere affirmation.

Comment: Right. This is [**Negative Concord**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), which is normal in most languages (Sp _No sé nada,_ Fr _Je ne regrette rien_) but not in formal English. Formal English uses [**Negative Polarity**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) instead.

Comment: Found in some varieties of British English too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found an answer, though I couldn't find it by searching before.

The question is a duplicate of
[The grammaticality of "that don't impress me much"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)